# Javamail on Android can't get multipart message contents? It works on latest version of javamail though

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, multipart

So my problem is simple. When i use the latest version of javamail on a normal java program i can do execute this code :

```
Multipart m = (Multipart) m.getContent();
```

However on android ported javamail that throws an exception complaining that it cannot cast it. Is there any other ways around this? A newer version of android javamail perhaps, or another way to get body contents from a multipart email? Thanks

Comment: See this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628395/javamail-parsing-email-content-cant-seem-to-get-it-to-work-message-getcont/26142591#26142591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the anwser to my own question. Using the old version on android simply works. So there is no need to change anything.

Comment: I'm in the exact same place right now. I just posted a question about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622877/problems-retrieving-emails-from-gmail-in-android-app/8622888#8622888 I'm trying to get the contents of multipart messages and have no idea how to. Is there any way you can help me out by posting your code that you got working?