# Problems retrieving emails from gmail in Android app

Tags: android, gmail

I'm using the java mail api built into java to get the mail of a user from their gmail box, most of the code i found in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928608/reading-the-full-email-from-gmail-using-javamail). And I'm able to pull most of the information i want correctly, like the subject, senders and other info from my mailbox.

Everything works great except when i go to pull the "content" of the message it doesnt always pull the content of the message. Only like 1 in 10 times it works. The other 9 times it just finds "`javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@40e9c920`"

My code is below. I'm printing the output into `LogCat` to test. Thanks in advance.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "Email address here",
                    "password here");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
            for (Message message : messages)
                Log.d("Email", message + "");
            Message message[] = inbox.getMessages();
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                        Log.d("From", message[i].getFrom()[0] + "");
                        Log.d("Subject", message[i].getSubject() + "");
                        String content = message[i].getContent().toString();
                        Log.d("content", content + "");
                        
                    }
```

Edit:
After some additional research I've found it has something to do with reading a multipart email with JavaMail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem the reason it wasn't working all the time is that when it found multipart messages it was unable to read them. Below is the solution to read multipart emails. I found most of the code [on this website](http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/ReadMultipartMail.shtml).

```
String s = message[i].getContent() + "";

                    if(s.indexOf("MimeMultipart") != -1){
                        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message[i].getContent();

                          for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount(); x++) {
                          BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);

                          String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();
                          //Log.d("disposition", disposition + "");

                          if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                              System.out.println("Mail have some attachment : ");

                              DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                              System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());
                              } else {
                              System.out.println(bodyPart.getContent());
                              }
                              }
                              System.out.println();



                          }

                    else
                        Log.d("Content", message[i].getContent() + "");

                }
```

Comment: i didnt copy your answer but your logic helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

`imap.gmail.com` **replaced by** `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks but its still the same :/

Comment: I think you need to add port as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but how would I do that?

Comment: checkout this link http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114408

Comment: Probably there would be method like store.port(465); try checking it

Comment: Added the port number but still no luck :/

Comment: does your inbox has 25 messages ? as you are using 25 in loop variable

Comment: I use 25 because my inbox has hundreds of messages and i wanted to limit the test to 25. Also i found else ware my issue has something to do with trying to read the contents of multipart messages. Thank you for your help though

Comment: you welcome dear, sorry that my knowledge was limited. so this was all i could help you.

Comment: Hey I'll take any help I can get :)

Comment: sure Peter, this website is for that purpose only. Knowledge sharring is a part of learning.