# MimeMultipart message dump with boundaries

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, multipart

I'm trying to log MimeMultipart message with the code which looks like

```
MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = null;
try {
    mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) msg.getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

for (int i = 0; i < mimeMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
    String contentType = bodyPart.getContentType();
    bodyPart.writeTo(outStream);
}

outStream.flush();
String content = new String(outStream.toByteArray());
LOGGER.info("Raw message: \r\n" + content);
```

but that looks like only a content of MimeMultipart message not a raw message (missing boundaries and headers).

Also I have tried just

```
msg.writeTo(outStream);
String content = outStream.toString();
```

but for some reason it just dump main message header but no body parts with headers for multiparts and looks like

```
Date: Fri, 31 May 2019 14:19:36 -0400 (EDT)
From: postmaster@dev.box.local
To: user@dev.box.local
Message-ID: <1293434275.167.1559326776862.JavaMail@devbox>
In-Reply-To: <984954674.27.1559326769277.JavaMail@devbox>
Subject: Re:
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report;
  boundary="----=_Part_166_602016356.1559326776861";
  report-type=delivery-status
```

What I have done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `msg.writeTo(outStream);`

Comment: I have done that before but for some reason it just dump main message header but no body parts with headers for multiparts.

Comment: Show me.  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: JavaMail 1.4.3 and I have updated OP with the raw message dump

Comment: 1.4.3 is almost 10 years old, although I don't think that's the source of your problem.  Still, you might want to upgrade to 1.6.3.  Can you include a small program that reproduces the problem, along with the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug)?  Thanks.

Comment: To reproduce it will require to run Apache James 3.0.0 and trigger DSN bounce message.

Comment: Mostly I want to see the code you're using to write out the message and the debug output.  It could be that the Apache James IMAP server is not returning the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689614/578855

It seems like the MimeMultiPart can have bodyparts those are itself MimeMultiPart so you have to recursively read the content.

Comment: But I think I should to see all parts (headers and related content) when I will do `msg.writeTo(outStream);`