# Getting empty email body while parsing eml to json only when eml contains attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am writing transform to convert eml to JSON. I have written the below code to parse eml. I want to extract the mail body and attachments from the eml. But whenever eml contains attachments I get an empty body and if eml does not contain attachments then I get an email body.

```
package org.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Class which transform EML file into JSON
 */
public class EMLtoJSONJavaTransform {

    private static final String FORWARD_EMAIL_PREFIX = "Fwd:";
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int OUTPUT_FILE_INDEX = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String emlFilePath = args[INPUT_FILE_INDEX];
        String jsonFilePath = args[OUTPUT_FILE_INDEX];

        try {
            File inputFile = new File(emlFilePath);
            File outputFile = new File(jsonFilePath);
            EMLtoJSONJavaTransform obj = new EMLtoJSONJavaTransform();
            obj.executeTransform(inputFile, outputFile);
            System.out.println("Conversion completed. JSON file saved to " + jsonFilePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private File executeTransform(File inputFile, File outputFile)  {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            // Read the .eml file
            InputStream emlInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            MimeMessage emlMessage = new MimeMessage(session, emlInputStream);

            // Convert the email message to JSON
            ObjectNode jsonNode = convertEmlToJson(emlMessage);

            // Write JSON to a file
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            objectMapper.writeValue(outputFile, jsonNode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputFile;
    }

    private ObjectNode convertEmlToJson(MimeMessage emlMessage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ObjectNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
        String subject = emlMessage.getSubject();
        if(subject.contains(FORWARD_EMAIL_PREFIX)) {
            subject = subject.substring(4).trim();
        }

        String sender = emlMessage.getFrom()[0].toString();
        int startIdx = sender.indexOf("<");
        int endIdx = sender.indexOf(">");

        // Extract relevant email properties and content
        jsonNode.put("sender", sender.substring(startIdx+1, endIdx));
        jsonNode.put("summary", subject);


        // Process the email body
        String bodyText = extractTextFromMessage(emlMessage);
        jsonNode.put("body", bodyText);
        Map<String, String> map = extractAttachmentsFromMessage(emlMessage);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNodeMap = mapper.convertValue(map, JsonNode.class);
        jsonNode.put("attachments", jsonNodeMap);

        return jsonNode;
    }

    private String extractTextFromMessage(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result.append(message.getContent());
        } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    result.append(bodyPart.getContent());
                }
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private Map<String, String> extractAttachmentsFromMessage(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {
                    // This is an attachment
                    String fileName = MimeUtility.decodeText(bodyPart.getFileName());
                    System.out.println("Attachment Name: " + fileName);

                    // Get the attachment content in base64 format
                    DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                    InputStream inputStream = handler.getInputStream();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                    inputStream.read(bytes);
                    String base64Content = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
                    map.put(fileName, base64Content);
//                    System.out.println("Base64 Content: " + base64Content);
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

The output of my code:

1. When eml contains an attachment

   ```json
   {
     "sender" : "xyz@abc.com",
     "summary" : "Sending test email",
     "body" : "",
     "attachments" : {
       "third attachment.png" : "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"
     }
   }
   ```
2. When eml not contain attachment

   ```json
   {
     "sender" : "abc@xyz.com",
     "summary" : "Sending test email",
     "body" : "---------- Forwarded message ---------\r\nFrom: abc <abc@xyz.com>\r\nDate: Wed, Aug 23, 2023 at 9:39 AM\r\nSubject: Fwd: Sending test email\r\nTo: abc <abc@xyz.com>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n---------- Forwarded message ---------\r\nFrom: abc <abc@xyz.com>\r\nDate: Wed, Aug 23, 2023 at 1:55 AM\r\nSubject: Sending test email\r\nTo: abc <abc@xyz.com>\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is mail body \r\n\r\nThanks,\r\npqr\r\n",
     "attachments": { }
   }
   ```

Help me to figure out my mistake.

Comment: Have you tried to open the input file with a text editor/viewer?  Perhaps the mail has an HTML body only but your code expects a "text/plain" MIME type.

Comment: The file containing the attachment has all three tags

1. Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8", 
2. Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8", 
3. Content-Type: image/png; name="third attachment.png" 

File not containing attachments have only two tags

1. Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" 
2. Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read text inside body of mail using javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240368/how-to-read-text-inside-body-of-mail-using-javax-mail)

Comment: Please provide the example emails.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel file content is too large to add here

Comment: Then you should do your best to create minimal emails that allows you to reproduce it. I haven't touched JakartaMail in a while, but I guess you're decoding the body structure incorrectly.