# reading body part of a mime multipart

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, multipart

ok so I use .getcontent and receive javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@fd13b5 etc.

I know i need something like this in my code but i dont know what exactly is needed.

```
if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
    pr("This is plain text");
    pr("---------------------------");
    if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments)
    System.out.println((String)p.getContent());
} else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
    pr("This is a Multipart");
    pr("---------------------------");
    Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
    level++;
    int count = mp.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
    level--;
} else if (p.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
    pr("This is a Nested Message");
    pr("---------------------------");
    level++;
    dumpPart((Part)p.getContent());
    level--;
```

at the moment i am trying to put all the information in to astring which is then shown up on a GUI at the moment i have it all working fine bar the body content which is showing as.
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@fd13b5. any help would be much appreciated as im quite stuck.

```
package EmailTable;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class Email implements ActionListener
{

private mail mail;
private List mails;
private String password;
private String user;
private String getText;
private boolean textIsHtml = false;

public Email(List mails,String password,String user) throws MessagingException,     IOException {

password = "password";
user = "user";
this.mails = mails;
String host = "10..10.10.10";
   Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
  Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
  store.connect(host, user, password);
  Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
  folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
  Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();

    int length = messages.length-1;
    for (int i = length; i > length-30; i--) {

            mail = new mail();

            mail.setEmail(messages[i].getFrom()[0]);

              String to = InternetAddress.toString(
                                messages[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                      if (to != null) {
                          mail.setEmail2(to);
                      }

            mail.setSubject(messages[i].getSubject());

            mail.setDate(messages[i].getSentDate());

            mail.setMessage(messages[i]);

             mail.setContent(((MimeMessage)messages[i]).getContent());



            Email.this.mails.add(mail);
  }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: See this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628395/javamail-parsing-email-content-cant-seem-to-get-it-to-work-message-getcont/26142591#26142591

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you have to iterate through each BodyPart to know it's type and then get the content accordingly. Here's what I used to get the content of a message. But still I am not able to get the right content for some messages.
**Edited**
Works better after implementing the code suggested by Bill.

```
    Object msgContent = messages[i].getContent();

    String content = "";             

     /* Check if content is pure text/html or in parts */                     
     if (msgContent instanceof Multipart) {

         Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msgContent;

         Log.e("BodyPart", "MultiPartCount: "+multipart.getCount());

         for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {

          BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(j);

          String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

          if (disposition != null && (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase("ATTACHMENT"))) { 
              System.out.println("Mail have some attachment");

              DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
              System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());                                 
            }
          else { 
                  content = getText(bodyPart);  // the changed code         
            }
        }
     }
     else                
         content= messages[i].getContent().toString();
```

Comment: I've looked at that and i didnt understand what half of it meant like were did P come from etc.

Comment: p is the Part/bodypart object that you would have to pass to the method, to the get content out of it. See the my edited answer, specially the `else` statement

Comment: @ThePCWizard Can you tell me for checking if attachment is present do we need to check Content-Id also. i.e if Content-Id is not blank then the body part is an attachment ?    like in this code->  if ( (null != disp1 && !"".equals(disp1)) && (disp1.equalsIgnoreCase(javax.mail.Part.ATTACHMENT) || disp1.equalsIgnoreCase(javax.mail.Part.INLINE)) ) {
    isAttachment = true;
   }else if (!"".equals(contentId)){
    isAttachment = true;
   }

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked much better for me. I merely wanted to log my email message for development/testing purposes. Use the MimeMessage.writeTo(OutputStream) method.

```
void logMimeMessage(MimeMessage msg) throws MessagingException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        msg.writeTo(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.catching(new MyException("Cannot log MimeMessage",e));
    }
    logger.error(out.toString());
}
```

Thanks to the comment by @zzzzz above, who linked to this answer [JavaMail - Parsing email content, can't seem to get it to work! (Message.getContent())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628395/javamail-parsing-email-content-cant-seem-to-get-it-to-work-message-getcont/26142591#26142591)