# Unable to read email content using Java

Tags: java, email

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
try {
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "xxx", "xxx");
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
for (int i = messages.length;i>=0; i--) {
Message message =messages[i];

System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
}
```

I am able to read emails and I am trying to get email content for each email.However getContent method returns junk value eg:(Text:javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@17ff24f).
How do I get complete email content. Please help.

Comment: It seems you are getting a buffered stream of the mail content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474705/reading-body-part-of-a-mime-multipart

Answer (score 1):

The call to `message.getContent()` doesn't return "junk value", it just returns something that cannot be directly converted into a `String` value.

That is because it's an object of class [`MimeMultipart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html). This means the email you're reading consists of multiple 'parts'. You can downcast the result of `message.getContent()` to a `MimeMultipart` variable and analyse it:

```
MimeMultipart multipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
System.out.println("This message consists of " + multipart.getCount() + " parts");
for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
    // Note we're downcasting here, MimeBodyPart is the only subclass
    // of BodyPart available in the Java EE spec.
    MimeBodyPart bodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i); 

    System.out.println("Part " + i + " has type " + bodyPart.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Part " + i " + has filename " + bodyPart.getFileName()); // if it was an attachment
    // So on, so forth.
}
```

See the [Javadoc of `MimeBodyPart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html) for details on how to analyse the parts of the message.