# How to parse string and extract data in key - value form?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to parse string created from email content and extract data. Structure of a email looks like this:

```
Some email text..............
//these properties I have to extract
Name: SomeName
Surname: SomeSurname
Email: SomeEmail
Adress: some adress
etc...
Some email text................
```

Do you know some techniques, how to parse this string and extract data? 
I find some way but it is defective, becouse it not works when value has whitespace, just like Adress above.

```
    String searchText = "Name:";
    int lastIndexOf = content.lastIndexOf(searchText);
    String substring = content.substring( 1 + lastIndexOf + searchText.length());
    String substring1 = substring.substring(0, substring.indexOf(" "));
```

Comment: this looks like yaml, possibly use a java yaml parser..., or a simple `content.split(':')`, and trim the results if they are not null

Comment: java.util.Properties can be a way

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for your solution:

```
    FileReader file;
    String sCurrentLine;
    String searchString = "Name";
    try {
        file = new FileReader("D:\\junk\\Sample.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\junk\\Sample.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String splitString = sCurrentLine.substring(0, sCurrentLine.indexOf(':'));
            splitString = splitString.replace(" ", "");
            if (splitString.equalsIgnoreCase(searchString)) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine.substring(sCurrentLine.indexOf(':')).replace(":",""));
                break;
            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Let me explain the code:
Here we are taking input from a text file. The text file contains the `key-value` mappings
Once we read the file, we parse it into a `String` in this case `sCurrentLine`

Then, we first split the String from the `':'` and then we remove any blank spaces and then store the split String in `splitString` This becomes out key without spaces.

Then we match the `splitString` with the `searchString`. If matched, then we print the part of the String which is after the `':'`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, read line by line would be solution but in my case I can't read line by line becouse I get this String from javax.mail.Message (as content), so this String have only one line.

Comment: In that case, you need to convert the javax.mail.Message to String and then follow the solution approach provided above. In that case the while -loop is not needed. Only the logic inside the while-loop can be used,where sCurrentLine will be the String you will get after convert the javax.mail.Message feed. Please refer to the following links for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240368/how-to-read-text-inside-body-of-mail-using-javax-mail and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474705/reading-body-part-of-a-mime-multipart

Comment: If the string really is only one line with no newlines, I don' t know how you tell where one field ends and the next begins.  But if it's a single string that contains multiple lines, as displayed above, you can use a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) (instead of FileReader) to read the lines in the string.  This won't be the most efficient approach, but it's easy.

Comment: And depending on the exact format of the data, you might be able to use the [InternetHeaders](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders.html) class to read the data.